# DNS server not responding on one machine on network

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, windows-10

We have a network with a Primary Domain Controller running Windows Server 2016 and acting as the primary DNS, a desktop running Windows 10, and a laptop running Windows 10.

This morning, the laptop was acting squirelly and I rebooted.  Since I rebooted, I'm getting "DNS Server isn't responding" on any internet access.  Both the Server and the Desktop are working fine.  I've compared the DNS server configuration as shown by ipconfig on the laptop and the desktop, and they are identical. I've tried doing nslookup cmds on the laptop directed to the external DNS servers, and the respond "DNS request timed out."

Event log has quite a number of DNS Client errors, mostly basically saying it can't reach the DNS server.

I'm baffled.  I had a similar problem a few months ago, and it was resolved by rebooting all the machines, but that has not helped this time.

Answer (score 0):

A miss-config on the network configuration or where it's connected (cable vs wifi) most probably.

If you are connected by a cable, please make sure the laptop wifi is at off and that you are really connected to your corporate network.

Issue a ipconfig /release, ipconfig /release and watch if your DHCP server can issue you a lease.

If yes, an ipconfig /all will give you the dhcp server IP, you should be able to ping it. If yes, after try to ping your DNS server, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had checked most of that before, but I hadn't checked the source of the DHCP information.  On the desktop, it was coming from the PDC, but on the laptop it was coming from the wireless router.  The laptop is connected by WiFi, while the desktop is hardwired.  However, correcting that didn't change anything.  Also, that configuration hadn't change in some time.

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon. After changing the router config to not act as DHCP server, and doing a ipconfig /release followed by ipconfig /renew, nothing had changed.  But when I rebooted, everything started working. Thanks for the help.